# How do I map an insert only table with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a scenario where I have a parent class with some definitions we can call if Foo to be unique and then a child class that I chose to call Bar. Together they make Foo Bar! :)

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }

    // Internal id only, should probably not even map it
    public virtual int Id { get; set; } 
    // A hashed searchable id
    public virtual string UId { get; set; } 
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long Version { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual SomeHash { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I can map this quite easily in both fluently and with xml. What I don't know how to map is the following scenario: I need to never update anything here. As soon as something changes I should just insert a new row. Never update or delete and I can't find any information about solving this even though I know this should indeed be possible. How do I tell NHibernate that every change in the version table should cause an insert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the mutable property of the class element. According to the [documentation](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html), setting it to false prevents UPDATE and DELETE

Answer (score 2):

In Fluent you can call the Readonly property which maps to the `access="readonly"` attribute.

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        ReadOnly();

        Id(x => x.Id).ReadOnly();
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I've never used it though, so I'm not sure it will work for what you need.

Comment: It is what Josh refers to as Mutable. I prefer they had not changed all the names in fluent :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use blank `<sql-update>` and `<sql-delete>` tags in you mapping.  these should get called when the class tries to update or delete.  but the nhibernate should still do the insert